# Android - Custom view with custom button makes entire screen clickable instead of just in button area

Tags: java, android, android-layout

UPDATED

This update is to provide clarification to the original question. I created custom views to make clickable dots. I did it this way to make sure I could always position the dots in the exact spot on different screen sizes. Even though the custom view only has a dot on a small portion of the screen, it makes the entire screen clickable so other parts cannot be clicked. I placed two dots on the screen but since the view for one dot actually takes up the entire screen it is impossible to click the other dot. How can I limit the clickable area of the custom view to only the part that has the dot drawn on it?

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final float dotScale = 0.3f;
Dot dot1, dot2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    MyView myView = new MyView(this);
    myLayout.addView(myView);

    // Two dots are created.

    dot1 = new Dot(this);
    dot1.xOffset = 2.9f;
    dot1.yOffset = 3.3f;
    myLayout.addView(dot1);
    dot2 = new Dot(this);
    dot2.xOffset = -2.4f;
    dot2.yOffset = 1.1f;
    myLayout.addView(dot2);

    // Makes dots clickable

    dot1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!dot1.isClicked) {
                dot1.animate().setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator())
                        .scaleXBy(dotScale).scaleYBy(dotScale).alpha(1.0f);
                dot1.isClicked = true;
            }
        }
    });

    dot2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!dot2.isClicked) {
                dot2.animate().setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator())
                        .scaleXBy(dotScale).scaleYBy(dotScale).alpha(1.0f);
                dot2.isClicked = true;
            }
        }
    });

}

.......

//custom view for Dots

class Dot extends View {

    int radius;
    float xOffset;
    float yOffset;
    boolean isClicked = false;

    public Dot(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setClickable(true);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();
        double ratio = (547d / 828d);
        float circleX = (float)((x / 2) - (y * ratio) / xOffset);
        float circleY = (float)(y / yOffset);

        radius = (int)((float)y/13);
        setPivotX(circleX);
        setPivotY(circleY);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, paint);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem. The view used to create each dot takes up the entire screen, even though some parts are transparent. There is a way to make it so clicks on a transparent area do not register. However, this is not a good solution. The way I solved the problem was to scrap the custom view idea and switch to standard views. Before I was unable to get the standard views to line up correctly on different screen sizes. However, after removing the top menu bar, the calculation was easier and I was able to get the calculation to work so the dots would always show up correctly on all screen sizes. Below is the code I used to create the dots that allowed both to be clickable:

```
    //get screen size
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;

    //create dots
    dot1 = new View(this);
    dot2 = new View(this);
    dot1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height/7, height/7);
    params.leftMargin = (int)((width / 2) - height * ratio / 2.6f);
    params.topMargin = (int)(height / 4.6f);
    myLayout.addView(dot1, params);


    dot2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height/7, height/7);
    params2.leftMargin = (int)((width / 2) - height * ratio / -4.6f);
    params2.topMargin = (int)(height / 1.4f);
    myLayout.addView(dot2, params2);
```